# assigning to list variable datatable object datetime

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, type-conversion

item["firstTime"] is DateTime object which may be NULL

If I use this:

```
firstDate= Convert.ToDateTime(item["firstTime"].ToString()),
```

while dataobject has some data inside everything is OK.
But if dataobject is NULL then I have error.
I've tried this but it won't help :(

```
    firstDate= Convert.ToDateTime(string.IsNullOrEmpty(item["firstTime"].ToString()) ?
 "NULL" : item["firstTime"].ToString()),
```

Comment: Why you convert `firstTime` to a string at all? Maybe it is already a nullable DateTime. What is `item`, a `DataRow`?

Comment: What is the type of `item["firstTime"]`? Check against null should be enabled before `DateTime` conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of your title i guess `item` is a `DataRow`. I don't understand why you convert the object to a string when it actually should be (and probably already is) a `DateTime`.

You should try this, if it works it's the best approach:

```
DateTime? firstDate = item.Field<DateTime?>("firstTime");
```

[`Field`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field?view=netframework-4.7.2) is an extension method that supports nullable types. So if the DataTable's column is actually a `DateTime`-column but it contains `DbNull` then this will assign a `DateTime?` to the variable.

If you want the string `NULL` in case it is null:

```
string result = firstDate?.ToString() ?? "NULL";
```

Comment: That solved the problem! Thanks you are absolutely right! will mark answer as Accepted after 6 min ;)